Android BLE: Difference between ScanResult.getTxPower() and ScanRecord.getTxPowerLevel()?
I'm a little bit confused about 'transmission power' with regard to Bluetooth LE and especially when using the android.bluetooth.le package.
There are two different methods to get data about transmission power:

ScanResult.getTxPower()
ScanRecord.getTxPowerLevel()

and the explanations for them on developer.android.com are not very clear.
I also looked up other BLE libraries and have the feeling, that 'transmission power' and 'transmission power level' are sometimes used interchangeably, e.g. some use a method called getTxPower to indeed receive the transmission power level.
However, my understanding is that in Android BLE ScanRecord.getTxPowerLevel() is returning the power level for BLE transmission that was set on the sending device. Thus this value is per se not dependent from the distance of sending and receiving device. I.e. when I scan, this value will be constant for the same device, and usually devices use some 'typical' values, e.g. like 12 (dBm)
But what is returned by ScanResult.getTxPower() ? In some references this is defined as RSSI at 1 m distance (also sometimes called 'calibrated transmission power'). Is this also a constant value for the given device, that is e.g. set by the manufacturer? Or is this a value that is somehow measured during scanning?
Or are both methods just 'synomyms' and are expected to return the same value?
I'm asking because I'm playing around with Android BLE but I have never seen a device during scanning where ScanRecord.getTxPower() returns a value except 127 (TX_POWER_NOT_PRESENT), while at least a few devices advertise TxPowerLevel. And I would like to know which property of Android's Bluetooth LE package correspond to which property of other systems' BLE libraries from e.g. Windows or Mac.

The difference is the direction in which these objects/packets are used.
If your application performs a Bluetooth LE scan, you will receive a ScanRecord for the devices found, which can contain a TxPowerLevel element if this was also sent by the transmitter.
You use a ScanResult object to specify which data your device advertises, e.g. a TxPower element.

Thank you, but I don't think this answers my question. When I do a BLE scan, I receive a ScanResult object from which I can retrieve the ScanRecord (ScanResult.getScanRecord()). My question is, what are actually the values that are returned from ScanResult.getTxPower() and ScanRecord.getTxPowerLevel() and what do they stand for? Set transmission power of the BLE chip, received signal strength at 1 m?

This is my understanding of these values (also what our production app is doing without issues so far):
ScanResult.getTxPower()
This delivers a relative sending signal strength in dBm. A value of 0 means: Default strength, 4: More power, -18: Less power (but longer battery life). This value is usually set by the manufacturer to 0 but can for most devices be changed by the user to adapt the BLE device to different use cases. It can also be used when ranging as context to the rssi (incoming signal strength), at least to compare multiple devices.
ScanRecord.getTxPowerLevel()
This is the calibrated signal strength, i.e., the signal strength (rssi) measured by a reference device at a distance of 1 meter (following the iBeacon standard). Values are usually around -60. So, in theory, if you receive a BLE advertisement frame with a rssi of -60, you can assume it to be 1 meter away. In practice, there is quite some variation :/
This value is set by the manufacturer and should be calibrated per device individually. In practice it's mostly set to the same value for all devices of the same model.
Also: We could not find a standard for how txPower influences txPowerLevel. Some devices seem to simply add the user-set txPower to the txPowerLevel, so that when you set txPower to -4 txPowerLevel goes to -64 - while others always deliver the same txPowerLevel regardless of changed txPower.

So this is exactly the opposite to my understanding written in my question. I had thought that TxPowerLevel is the user settable value (in certain steps) while 'TxPower` is the calibrated signal strenght.

Weird :D
Anyway, just tested again what I have written there with the beacons I have flying around here (Averos CoreBlu), and what I've written is correct.
